# Reverse fibonacci series in php using do while loop

Tags: php

I am trying reverse Fibonacci series in PHP which is not working.

Inputs will be 2 numbers, output should be reverse Fibonacci till 0 (should not go in negative).
Ex - inputs 55, 34 - Output - 55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0

```
function reverseFibonacci($n)
{

// assigning first and
// second elements
$a[0] = 0;
$a[1] = 1;

for ($i = 2; $i < $n; $i++)
{

    // storing sum in the
    // preceding location
    $a[$i] = $a[$i - 2] +
             $a[$i - 1];
}

for ($i = $n - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
{

    // printing array in
    // reverse order
    echo($a[$i] . " ");
}
}
```

But I want to use do while loop. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate with `while (lastValue > 0)`, it will make sure the looping will stop reverse fibonacci pattern inside the looping function when the last value is `0`.

```php
<?php
function reverseFibonacci($a, $b) {
    $n = [$a, $b];
    $resultArr = [$n[0], $n[1]];
    while($n[1] > 0) {
        $temp = $n[1];
        $n[1] = $n[0] - $n[1];
        $n[0] = $temp;
        $resultArr[] = $n[1];
    }
    echo join(', ', array_unique($resultArr));
}

echo reverseFibonacci(55, 34);
?>
```

The output will be:

```
55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0
```

Demo : https://3v4l.org/fHjNo